# In Gmail Web,unable to access "Create Account" menu Options, I can't capture the menu item "Para mim" throws exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I've tried everything !!. I need to inspect the "for me"  from button "Criar Item.

```
public void que_eu_esteja_na_pagina_principal_do_gmail() throws Throwable {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Browsers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Criar conta')]")).click();

    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Kindly refer the below for your reference

[image]

Comment: Whats the issue you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code its working for me in gmail.com(UK)

```
public static void TestGmail throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Your driver path");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"I3EnF oJeWuf\"]//span[@class=\"NlWrkb snByac\"]")).click(); //<--Modified xpath
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"xkfVF nnGvjf\"]//div[@class=\"JPdR6b ILYVD qjTEB\"]//span[@class=\"z80M1 G3hhxb\"]//div[@class=\"uyYuVb oJeWuf\"]//div[@class=\"jO7h3c\"]")).click(); //<--Modified xpath
        driver.close();
}
```

Comment: That xPath is so long, that's not easy to read and it's more prone to bugs. Try to simplify it as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you X 1000   we are the best!!!... 
I love you all!!..

Comment: Thank'u X 1000...

Comment: @pavelsaman i will make it

Comment: @RebekaMontana please upvote the answer if you accept it

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly fine :

Just add some sleep ( In your actual code add explicit wait for "//div[contains(text(),'Para mim')]" to be visible )

```
public void que_eu_esteja_na_pagina_principal_do_gmail() throws Throwable {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Browsers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Criar conta')]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Para mim')]")).click();
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

you can use the xpath 'or' statement for testing website that has different language support.

```
//span[contains(text(),'Criar conta') or contains(text(),'Create account')]
```

Comment: Ohh my good, we are the best!!!... 
I love you all!!..

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to my answer

Comment: @RebekaMontana you can accept only one answer. All the best with you learning

Comment: @PDHide The xpath you mentioned is language dependent. Whether it will work in Gmail UK?

Comment: @MohamedSulaimaanSheriff Thanks for the question, you can use the xpath 'or' statement for testing website that has different language support.   //span[contains(text(),'Criar conta') or contains(text(),'Create account')]